# Php Mysql call is rendering after other html elements?

Tags: php, html, css, mysqli, html-table

I'm finishing up a project for university and having issues with my html rendering correctly, as it stands the below code should

```
div
render title
render table
/div

div
render footer
/div
```

It's currently

```
div
render title
div
render footer
/div
render footer
/div
```

Could someone point out where the error is?

```
<body>

<div class="content main">
<h2>Status Posting System</h2>
<?php

    require_once ("settings.php"); 

    $search = $_GET["search"];

    $conn = @mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pswd)
    or die('Failed to connect to server');

    @mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbnm)
    or die('Database unavailable');

    $query = "SELECT * FROM status WHERE status like '%" . $search . "%'";
    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    echo "<table width='100%' border ='1'>";
    echo "<tr><th>Status Code</th><th>Status</th><th>Share</th><th>Permission</th>
    <th>Date</th></tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    echo "<tr><td> {$row['code']}</td>";
    echo "<td> {$row['status']}</td>";
    echo "<td> {$row['share']}</td>";
    echo "<td> {$row['permission']}</td>";
    echo "<td> {$row['date']}</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }

    mysqli_free_result($results);
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
</div>

<div class="padding-footer"><a class="footer" href="index.php">Return Home</a></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have edited your question, but I think it;s still not quite clear - maybe clarify a bit what you mean by what the code does currently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your missing the

```
</table>
```

after the while. Don't know if that will solve your problem.